# I am unable to run my angular application

Tags: angular, environment-variables, configuration-files

I cloned the ever repo and i was trying to run the admin site but it didn't. The first problem was related to symlinks or shortcuts, implying the developers only had linux in mind and not windows. So i manually created and got it to work. But another error happened when i try to run the admin site made in angular

```
ERROR in app/@core/auth/auth.module.ts:6:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'environments/environment'.

6 import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is the error and others just like this one. When i looked for the file, it didn't exist. So can anyone tell me if the file is generated on compile time. And this project worked fine on ubuntu before without any of the problems mentioned above.

Comment: Should be great if you share the source repo.

Comment: https://github.com/ever-co/ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the `environment.ts` file doesn't exist on the repo, instead, they have `model.ts` inside `environment` folder. Replace the import statement in `app/@core/auth/auth.module.ts`.

**EDIT**
Read the documentation about how to run each project as stated [comment](https://github.com/ever-co/ever/issues/968#issuecomment-572225366).

> Run `yarn ts-node ./scripts/configure.ts`
>   and configure.ts generates automatically environment.ts file with setting defined in .env file (or default if you don't have .env.ts file at all)

Comment: But why did it work in ubuntu without changing a single line. Also that is to show the error but there are 16 more lines like it. Isn't there a configurations solution or something like that for it?